# How to wait for any element to appear in protractor

Tags: protractor, wait

I am new in Protractor and having issues in putting wait statement
My code is below:

```
element(by.xpath('html/body/app-root/div/app-dashboard/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/app-dashboard-filter/span/span/img')).click();
```

Before performing the click() operation I want protractor to wait for `'/html/body/app-root/div/app-dashboard/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/h5'` element. This element comes in 4 seconds

After searching the INTERNET, I have tried below things:

```
1. browser.driver.sleep(5000);
2. browser.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(55000);
3. expect(element(by.xpath(/html/body/app-root/div/app-dashboard/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/h5')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
4. browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
```

But due to one or the other error nothing worked for me. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

You can implement protractor.ExpectedConditions in your script to wait.

**Code:**

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var ele=element(locator)

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ele),timeout,"Custom Error Message");
```

Link for more ExpectedConditions:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/expectedConditions.ts

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in 2 ways.

1. To see if element is visible in DOM.
2. To see if element is visible in page.

1st point can be used if we use **ng-if** (since ng-if hides the element in DOM )

**Example:-**

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element),timeout,"Custom Error Message");
```

2nd point can be used in a normal way.

**Example:-**

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element),timeout,"Custom Error Message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use visibility check & elementToBeClickable expected conditions, it works.Please find the code snippet below:

```
 var targetEle = element(by.xpath(/html/body/app-root/div/app-dashboard/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/h5'));
    var EC_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(targetEle), EC_TIMEOUT).then(function(){
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(targetEle), EC_TIMEOUT).then(function(){
            //callback();
            targetEle.click().then(function() {
                callback();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Getting this error:
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(xpath, /html/body/app-root/div/app-dashboard/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/h5)

No change After adding this:
allScriptsTimeout: 15000,

Comment: If the page is not angular add the code : browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;